# Weird behaviour of electron.ipcMain

Tags: javascript, electron

Well this is more a javascript than electron question.

I have the following code:

```js
var electron = require("electron")

var registerTestHandler = function(onFn) {
    onFn("test", console.log)
}

electron.app.whenReady()
.then(function() {
    registerTestHandler(electron.ipcMain.on)
})
```

Running the app throws the following error:

```js
(node:14139) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of undefined
    at _addListener (events.js:228:19)
    at addListener (events.js:284:10)
    at registerTestHandler (/Users/marco/Desktop/electron-ipc-test/index.js:4:2)
    at /Users/marco/Desktop/electron-ipc-test/index.js:9:2
(node:14139) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of undefined
    at _addListener (events.js:228:19)
    at addListener (events.js:284:10)
    at registerTestHandler (/Users/marco/Desktop/electron-ipc-test/index.js:4:2)
    at /Users/marco/Desktop/electron-ipc-test/index.js:9:2
(node:14139) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14139) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14139) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:14139) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Now changing the code to:

```js
var electron = require("electron")

var registerTestHandler = function(ipc) {
    ipc.on("test", console.log)
}

electron.app.whenReady()
.then(function() {
    registerTestHandler(electron.ipcMain)
})
```

And it works fine!

I don't think that this has anything to do with electron but rather something with javascript.

However I can't explain why this happens.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23329) on the electron github page and got the following explanation:

> This is just the way javascript works, when you rip the on method off of ipcMain you are removing the this scope when you call that method in the future. i.e. if you explicitly bind it to ipcMain it will work